# CheckBoxList value problem, set to "ON"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, checkbox

I've got a simple CheckBoxList that I'm using to create some dynamic html on the client,  I'm using the value of each checkbox item on the client.  The text value comes across fine.  The problem I'm having is that the value of each checkbox item comes across as "on" vs the value I set on the server.  I've tried directly databinding to list, changing where the creation of the list is on the server side (OnInit vs OnPageLoad ) and nothing seems to change it.  I've gone as far a recreating the control in a separate project and it works fine.  Any ideas why the values aren't coming across? Thanks

Code on the user control

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblToolBarButtons" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Server code

```
foreach (EditorButton editorButton in editorToolBarButtons)
{
    ListItem liButton = 
          new ListItem(
               this.ResolveClientUrl(editorButton.ImageUrl).ToString(),
               editorButton.Id.ToString()
          );
    cblToolBarButtons.Items.Add(liButton);
}
```

Comment: Each checkbox in the list is selected, and this doesn't happen in your test environment with the same code?

Comment: What do you mean by "On", and where are your "On" values in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just add the id like this liButton .Attributes.Add("id", button.Id.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had this issue.

Make sure `ViewState` is enabled in your user control `Page_Load` (and in all of your UCs and your page and your master page).

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.EnableViewState = true;
}
```